# Declare string as a "constant" in sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to implement an algorithm which involves polynomials in two variables "x" and "y", but some times I need to interpret them as univariable polynomials (that is, leaving x as a *constant*), for example, in order use the function [gcdex](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html) (the extended euclidean algorithm). **Is there a simple way to make sympy interpret "x" as a constant instead of a variable?**

I've tried the following:

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x', constant=True)
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
f = sympy.Poly(x*y + y**2)
g = sympy.Poly(x+y)
(s, t, gcd) = sympy.gcdex(f,g)
```

but it throws an error: univariate polynomials expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to specify the generators of the polynomials when you create them. For instance, to treat only `y` as a variable, use

```
f = Poly(x*y + y**2, y)
```

By default, `Poly` assumes that all the symbols in an expression should be generators.

You can also pass the generator as the third argument to gcdex

```
s, t, gcd = gcdex(f, g, y)
```

gives

```
(s, t, gcd) == (Poly(0, y, domain='ZZ(x)'), Poly(1, y, domain='ZZ(x)'), Poly(x + y, x, y, domain='ZZ'))
```

Comment: Best birthday gift ever, man. I'll try it tomorrow and tell you how it goes.

Comment: If it interests you (as the lead developer of SymPy), I'm trying to implement a version of Hensel's lemma (so that I can later implement a couple algoritms for solving limits in three variables of the form p/q with p and q polynomials).

Comment: It may already be implemented in SymPy, although only in the lower level code. If not, it might be something we'd like to have included.